# difficult sentence meaning

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

What is the meaning of this sentence?

> ... because believing in something will be seen by the passive nihilist as preferable to taking the risk of not believing in anything, to taking the risk of staring into the abyss – a metaphor for nihilism that appears frequently in Nietzsche’s work.

One source: [Nihilism](https://aeon.co/essays/if-you-believe-in-nihilism-do-you-believe-in-anything)

Comment: The comma before "to taking" separates a rephrasing of the previous idea.

Comment: @WeatherVane , please could you explain this as well: "because believing in something will be seen by the passive nihilist as preferable to taking the risk of not believing in anything."

Comment: *because / believing in **something** / will be seen / by the passive nihilist / as preferable to / taking the risk / of not believing in **anything**.* I am not going to study nihilism though.

Comment: I think that analyzing the thoughts of Nietzsche is a step beyond even interpreting song lyrics.

Comment: @HotLicks I always liked the apocryphal graffiti 'conversation' which went "God is dead - Nietzsche" followed by, in a diferent hand, "Nietzsche's dead - God"

Answer (score 1):

> ... because believing in something will be seen by the passive
>   nihilist as preferable to taking the risk of not believing in
>   anything; *that is to say*, to taking the risk of staring into the abyss – a metaphor
>   for nihilism that appears frequently in Nietzsche’s work.

Here, "staring into the abyss" is just a restatement of "not believing in anything". Structurally, it means the same as this:

> ... because believing in something will be seen by the passive
>   nihilist as preferable to taking the risk of staring into the abyss, which is a metaphor
>   for nihilism that appears frequently in Nietzsche’s work.

Answer (score 0):

You're right. It's a tricky sentence.

Passive nihilists believe in something—*anything*—because any belief is better than no belief.

Apparently, active nihilists enjoy staring into the abyss.